# A connection is uniquely determined by its action on global sections

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\mathcal{A}^i(E)$ be the sheaf of $C^{\infty}$ differential $i-$form with values in $E$, where $\pi: E \mapsto M$ is a complex vector bundle. We define connection on $E$ a $\mathbb{C}-$linear sheaf homorphism

$
\nabla : \mathcal{A}^0(E) \mapsto \mathcal{A}^1(E)
$

which satisfies the Leibniz rule $\nabla (fs)=df \otimes s + f \nabla(s)$ for any local function $f$ on $M$ and any local section $s$ of $E$.

Now, using glueing, I expect that a connection is uniquely determined by its action on the space of global sections.
How can I prove this assertion formally?

Comment: It's all about partition of unity. First you can show that if $\alpha, \beta$ are local section which agree on some open set $V$, then $\nabla \alpha = \nabla \beta$ on $V$. In general, if $\alpha$ is a local section on $U$, then for all $x\in U$, there is $V\subset U$ and a global section $\beta $ so that $\beta|_V = \alpha|_V$.